# Optimization with integrals

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

Suppose $q \in [0,1]$ with continuous distribution $\Gamma$; $x,y$ are non-negative.

$$
\max_{I(\cdot)} \int_0^1 \log(1 + y + q - I(q))\, d\Gamma(q)\\
\text{subject to}\\
\int_0^1 \log(1 + x + I(q))\, d\Gamma(q) \geq w.
$$

How can I solve the problem? Under regularity conditions I can form the Lagrangian and obtain the first order conditions, but I cannot solve the integrals to obtain a closed form for $I(q)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\zeta$ be the Lagrange multiplier. Then the optimal solution $I(q)$ must satisfy
$$
-\int_0^1 (1 + y + q - I(q))^{-1} \, d\Gamma(q) + \zeta \int_0^1 (1 + x + I(q))^{-1} \, d\Gamma(q) = 0\\
\Leftrightarrow \int_0^1 \left(\zeta (1 + x + I(q))^{-1} - (1 + y + q - I(q))^{-1}\right) \, d\Gamma(q) = 0.
$$
A sufficient condition for the last equality to hold is
$$
\zeta (1 + x + I(q))^{-1} = (1 + y + q - I(q))^{-1}\\
\Leftrightarrow I(q) = \frac{-(1+x) + (1 + y + q)\zeta}{1 + \zeta}
$$
In addition, the optimal solution $I(q)$ must satisfy
$$
\int_0^1 \log(1 + x + I(q)) \, d\Gamma(q) \geq w,
$$
for which a sufficient condition is that
$$
\log(1 + x + I(q)) = w.
$$
Then
$$
\zeta = \frac{e^w}{2-e^w+q+x+y}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
I(q) = e^w-x-1.
$$